# how can i deallocate viewControllers in ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc, deinit

I made some views ordering like `Login -> Navigation Controller[Dashboard -> Detail]`

In LoginViewController, There is Login Button and it has `Action`

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any){
    let mainNavigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationViewController") as! MainNavigationViewController
    present(mainNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In NagivationController

There are two Views,`Dashboard` and `Detail`

`Detail` View is pushed by segue action from `Dashboard`

and `Dashboard` has tab bar Item to logout

I know that when `back button` is tapped in `Detail` view, It doesn't deallocating `Detail` View. It just push back to Navigation Controller's Stack (Is it right...?)

but when i tapped Logout Button in `Dashboard`, I thought Navigation Controller which contains two views (`Dashboard`, `Detail`) should be deallocated

but it doesn't deallocated.

I set the `deinit` method in Navigation View Controller like this

```
deinit {
    print("Main Navigation View Controller is deinited")
}
```

but it never called

How can i deallocate views that appear after login, when i tapped logout button

Sorry for poor syntax in English because i'm not Native

Comment: going back from the detail view should deallocate it unless something else is holding a strong reference to it. What code do you run when the logout button is tapped? Again, if you are dismissing the navigation controller correctly, it and and the dashboard view controller will be deallocated

Comment: @Paulw11 i use`presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) `